# Socket emit fails to reach UI

Tags: node.js, docker, socket.io, docker-swarm

We have a Node program which emit and listen sockets from UI (Angular 6). When deployed on Docker with no replicas it works fine. The moment we create replicas using Portainer the whole socket system fails. If there are 5 replicas then we do get the socket connection to server from client and it is processed by only one of the replica, but after the socket is emitted Angular does not get the response.

We tried from UI to send `{cookie:false}` so that every time there is new connection. Also we tried appyling `transport: ['websocket', 'pooling']` suggested but did not achieve anything.

No complex code, just the basic socket.io implementation.

Comment: It seems you have two typos in the same piece of code: `trasport` and `webcoscket` are both misspelled.

Comment: @halfer Yes u r right there , but it's a type mistake while writing here. in code it is perfectly fine.

Comment: OK. Would you fix it in the post, please? There is an [edit] button for the purpose.